# Required value in Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I need to put  the value of a `TextBox` required like this :

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>(m.Code), new { @required  = "required"})</td>
```

It works. But if i set a default value to the `TextBox`

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>(m.Code), new { @Value = @Model.Code, @required  = "required"})</td>
```

An empty value becomes accepted despite the generation of this Html code

```
<td><input id="Code" name="Code" required="required" type="text" value="fff       "></td>
```

1. What is the source of this problem?
2. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know why but when i delete the space between `=` and `@`

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>(m.Code), new { @Value =@Model.Code, @required  = "required"})</td>
```

it works

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
```

for validating the code property.and code Property should be define like this-

```
 [Required]
 public string Code{ get; set; }
```

and for setting the value in code Textbox.You can set it in controller like this.

```
Model.Code="fffff";
```

and on the view use like this-

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>(m.Code), new { @Value = @Model.Code)</td>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
```

and yes dont forgot to include the validation Js i.e

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Try it:-

Comment: Yes your validation should be in your models like in this post. It will become a mess if you do it on the view, especially when you want to do custom error messages.

Comment: How to do this dynamically rather than on submit?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the parens

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "txtCode" })
```

if you set code on the controller side the value will be put in the text box